# Excel pattern to skip every couple of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

what I currently have

```
D5 =[stock.xlsx]asda!$C12
D6 =[stock.xlsx]asda!$C18
D7 =[stock.xlsx]asda!$C24
D8 =[stock.xlsx]asda!$C30
```

I want to fill out the pattern up to D500 without manually adding each field.

Comment: In D5 `=INDIRECT("[stock.xlsx]asda!$C" & Row(2:2) * 6)` And copy down.

Comment: it works, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's recommended to avoid the use of volatile functions whenever possible.  `INDIRECT` is a volatile function, and its use should be minimized.  In this case, a viable alternative would be the `INDEX` function.  So given your provided information, in cell D5 and copied down you could use this formula:

```
=INDEX([stock.xlsx]asda!$C:$C,ROW(D2)*6)
```

The reason to avoid volatile functions is because they will recalculate on **every** change made in a worksheet, not just changes that affect their results.  This can dramatically slow down workbook speed and usability when you have many volatile functions.